# Finite potential well problem - calculating the ground state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, eigenvalue

**1. The problem statement, all variables and given/known data**

> Electron of is in a 1-D potential well of depth $20eV$ width $d=0.2 nm$ in his ground
>   state $N=1$. What is the energy of the ground state? Write the
>   normalized wavefunction of the ground state. What is the probability,
>   to find the particle outside the well?

**2. The attempt at a solution**

1st I draw the image of the well, so we can talk better - otherwise this makes no sense as it looks like a complex homework. In the image $W_p$ marks the potential energy but never mind I'll use $E_p$ notation.

[image]

Ok now that I have an image I can tell you what I already know and what is still unclear to me. And this is my 1st finite potential well homework problem so take it easy on me.

I know, that in a standard finite potential well, which is symmetric we have two possible wavefunctions - one is odd $\psi_{odd}$ and one is even $\psi_{even}$. They are both split into three separate functions which are different for each interval - I will name those $\psi_1,\psi_2,\psi_3$. Now let me write all those:

**For an odd solutions we have wavefunction:**

\begin{align}
\psi_{odd} = 
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
\psi_1&=Ae^{Kx}\\
\psi_2&=- \frac{ Ae^{-K\frac{d}{2}} }{ \sin \left( L \frac{d}{2} \right) }  \sin \left( Lx \right)\\
\psi_3&=-Ae^{-Kx}
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{align}

where $L=\sqrt{2mE / \hbar^2}$ and $K=\sqrt{-2m(E-E_p)/\hbar^2}$. These are the same even for "even solutions".

**For an even solutions we have wavefunction:**

\begin{align}
\psi_{even} = 
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
\psi_1&=Ae^{Kx} \longleftarrow\substack{\text{same as for the odd solutions}}\\
\psi_2&=\frac{ Ae^{-K\frac{d}{2}} }{ \cos \left( L \frac{d}{2} \right) }  \cos \left( Lx \right)\\
\psi_3&=Ae^{-Kx}
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{align}

By applying boundary condition for matching derivatives on these wavefunctions (even and odd) we always get *"transcendental equation"* - its LHS is different in case of odd and even wavefunctions while its RHS is the same in both cases:

**For an odd solutions we have transcendental equation:**

\begin{align}
-\sqrt{\frac{1}{E_p / E -1} } = \tan\left(\frac{\sqrt{2mE}}{\hbar}\frac{d}{2}\right)
\end{align}

**For an even solutions we have transcendental equation:**

\begin{align}
\sqrt{\frac{E_p}{E} - 1 } = \tan\left(\frac{\sqrt{2mE}}{\hbar}\frac{d}{2}\right)
\end{align}

Because the RHS is the same we can use the constraint that tangents is repeated every $N\pi$ and derive the equation for energies which we derived and it looks like this (solved for $N$):

$$
N = \frac{\sqrt{2mW}}{\pi\hbar} \frac{d}{2}
$$

*1st I would like to know if my equations until this point are correct.*

**3. What I don't understand**

I have to calculate energy of the ground state so I set $N=1$ in the last equation and calculated energy. I got result $37.64eV$ while the book says it is $4.4eV$... If I manage to calculate the energy I can afterwards calculate $L$ and $K$ which are needed by the wave function, so I need to start here I think.

Even if my obtained value for energy was correct I don't know on what criteria to decide which set of equations should I use (even or odd). I am guessing that for $N=1$ I should take odd ones. I am guessing that for $N=2$ I should then take even ones, but what about for $N=3$? **Notice that in the wavefunctions there are no $N$**... How do I plug $N$ in my equations? Where should I put it and how do I derive equations which include $N$?

Oh and there is one more thing. I don't know how to normalize $\psi_{odd}$ or $\psi_{even}$. Do I have to take a superposition of their subfunctions $\psi_1,\psi_2,\psi_3$?

---

*I will include the [hyperlink](http://www.physicsforums.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=60716&d=1375789716) to the derivation of the above equations (It is in Slovenian language but don't mind the language everything is there - I wrote it myself in latex  just in case it might come handy)*

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten, in analysing your transcendental equations, that $E$ is in the left hand side too.

So, you cannot say that "tangent is repeated every $n\pi$ and derive the equation for energies". No, the left-hand side changes with $E$ too.

There is no problem to normalize $\psi_{odd}$ or $\psi_{even}$. The domains of definition of $\psi_1,\psi_2,\psi_3$ are different.

So $\int dx |\psi(x)|^2 = \int_{- \infty}^{-d/2} dx |\psi_1(x)|^2 +\int_{-d/2}^{+d/2} dx |\psi_{2}(x)|^2 +\int_{+d/2}^{+ \infty} dx |\psi_{3}(x)|^2 $

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_potential_well) for more details.

Note that you did not give the value of $W_p$ and $m$, so it is not possible to give numerical results.

[EDIT]

Looking at even solutions, and applying continuity of the first derivative, we get :

$$K = L ~ \tan(\frac{Ld}{2}) \tag{1}$$
This could be written :

$$u_0^2 - v^2 = v ~ \tan v \tag{2}$$
with : $$ u_0= \frac{d}{2} \sqrt{\frac{2mE_p}{\hbar^2}}, v = \frac{d}{2} \sqrt{\frac{2mE}{\hbar^2}} \tag{3}$$

Numerical calculus gives :

$$u_o^2= 5.245\tag{4}$$

Solving equation $(2)$ with numerical value $(4)$ (see [plot1](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+plot%2C+x+tan%28+x%29+-+sqrt%285.245+-+%28x%29%5E2%29%2C+x%3D0%2C+1.5) and [plot2](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+plot%2C+x+tan%28+x%29+-+sqrt%285.245+-+%28x%29%5E2%29%2C+x%3D1.07%2C+1.09)) gives a numerical value for $v_1 = v(N=1)$:

$$v_1 = 1.08 \tag{5}$$

Finally, we have : $$E_1 = E_p \frac{v_1^2}{u_0^2}\tag{6}$$

So, numerically, it gives :

$$E_1 (eV) = 20 \frac{(1.08)^2}{5.245} = 4.45~ eV\tag{7}$$

Comment: Thank zou for the info about normalization. Concerning the numerical value - the particle is an electron so just use its mass, but i really forgot to give the depth of a potential well which is $20eV$. Do you use mathematica?

Comment: @71GA : I made an edit to the answer, with the solution

Answer (score 1):

There is a good [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_potential_well) about this topic. But let me solve this my own way.

\begin{align}
\large{\psi(x) = 
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
Ce^{Kx}+De^{-Kx}\\
Ae^{\mathfrak{i}Lx}+Be^{-\mathfrak{i}Lx}\\
Ee^{Kx}+Fe^{-Kx}
\end{aligned}
\right.
\begin{aligned}
x &\le -d/{2}\\
-d/{2} &\le x\le d/{2}\\
d/{2} &\le x
\end{aligned}}
\end{align}

And our boundary conditions are:

\begin{align}
\large{
\begin{aligned}
\psi(x)&=
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
0 & \ x \to -\infty \\
0 & \ x \to\infty
\end{aligned}
\right. \\ 
&\Rightarrow \left\{\begin{aligned}D &= 0 \\ E &= 0 \end{aligned} \right.
\end{aligned}}
\end{align}

Also, we know that $\psi$ and its first derivative must be continuous. This gives us more equations:

\begin{align}
\large{
\begin{aligned}
Ce^{-\frac{Kd}{2}} &= Ae^{-\mathfrak i \frac{Ld}{2}}+Be^{\mathfrak i \frac{Ld}{2}} \\
CKe^{-\frac{Kd}{2}} &= A\mathfrak{i}Le^{-\mathfrak i \frac{Ld}{2}}-B\mathfrak{i}Le^{\mathfrak i \frac{Ld}{2}}\\
Fe^{-\frac{Kd}{2}} &= Ae^{\mathfrak i \frac{Ld}{2}}+Be^{-\mathfrak i \frac{Ld}{2}} \\
-FKe^{-\frac{Kd}{2}} &= A\mathfrak{i}Le^{\mathfrak i \frac{Ld}{2}}-B\mathfrak{i}Le^{-\mathfrak i \frac{Ld}{2}}
\end{aligned}
}\end{align}

These four equations are not independent(otherwise the answer would be unique, and the obvious answer is $0$). Writing it in the matrix form:

\begin{align}
\begin{aligned}
\left(
\begin{matrix} e^{-\mathfrak i \frac{Ld}{2}} & e^{\mathfrak i \frac{Ld}{2}} & -e^{-\frac{Kd}{2}} & 0 \\ 
e^{\mathfrak i \frac{Ld}{2}} & e^{-\mathfrak i \frac{Ld}{2}} & 0 &-e^{-\frac{Kd}{2}}\\ 
\mathfrak i Le^{-\mathfrak i \frac{Ld}{2}} & -\mathfrak i Le^{\mathfrak i \frac{Ld}{2}} & -Ke^{- \frac{Kd}{2}} & 0 \\
\mathfrak i Le^{\mathfrak i \frac{Ld}{2}} & -\mathfrak i Le^{-\mathfrak i \frac{Ld}{2}} & 0 & Ke^{- \frac{Kd}{2}}
\end{matrix}\right) \left(\begin{matrix}A \\ B \\ C \\ F \end{matrix} \right)=\left( \begin{matrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{matrix}\right)
\end{aligned}
\end{align}

The determinant of this matrix has to be zero. It's not actually hard to calculate the determinant(it can be made lower-triangulated easily). The determinant is:

$$2 \mathfrak i e^{-d K} ((K^2-L^2) \sin (d L)+2 K L \cos (d L)) =0$$

This simplifies to:

$$(E_p- 2 E)\tan(d L)+ 2 \sqrt{E(E_p-E)}=0$$

This is a [transcendental equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation), and doesn't have algebraic solutions. But we can solve it numerically, to find the eigenvalues(or we can write $\tan\theta=\frac{2\tan\left( \frac{\theta}{2}\right)}{1-\tan^2\left( \frac{\theta}{2}\right)}$ and reproduce the equations given in the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_potential_well)). This way we don't have to struggle with the symmetry of our eigenstates, and specially the ground state(which happens to be symmetric). Using Mathematica I was able to find two discrete eigenvalues for energies:

$$E=4.44364 \text{eV} \\ E=15.8826\text{eV}$$

This method has another benefit, and that's it clarifies the nature of the eigenvalues and the reason they appear.

Comment: Wouldnt i get the energy of this state if i used hamiltonian on the wavefunction???

Comment: If you have the wavefunction, then sure.

Answer (score -2):

1) Energy of electron

$$E=\frac{n^2h^2}{8mL^2}$$
$E= 1.506 \times 10^{-18}\text{ Joules}$ 
 which if you divide by electron charge ie $1.6 \times 10^{-19}$ will give $E$ in electron volts ($eV$)

i.e. $E = 9.4135\text{ eV}$, so thats the energy of electron at $n=1$.

2)Normalized Wave Function

Need to find $K$ for that first.

$K = \frac{4\pi^2}{h^2}\sqrt{2mE}
  = 1.489 \times 10^{44}$

for normalization then follow equation: 122 from [this link](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/qmech/lectures/node33.html)

3) Probability can be found out by using equation: 121 from same link

Comment: This is only valid if the well is infinite, which is not the situation in this case.